# How to change background color of Paginator in Datatable component in angular5?

Tags: css, datatable, angular5, paginator

I have an p-datatable component with paginator enabled, How can I change the color of active page color in paginator?

.ts file

```
<p-dataTable  [value]="UsersObj" [rows]="2"  [paginator]="true">
    <p-column field="userEmail" header="Email ID"></p-column>
    <p-column field="userName" header="User Name"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

I want these css to be applied the the active page in paginator.

```
 background: #bdd755;
 color: #000000;
 border-color: #bdd755;
```

Comment: Are you using any package for datatable?

Comment: No, I am not using any package.